# Repeticion de la iteracion

Tags: javascript

estoy recorriendo un arreglo simple, pero me surge el siguiente problema. al mostrar la iteracion

```js
function init() {
  var countries = ['USA','France','Italy','Brazil','Colombia','Belize','Venezuela'];

  for(i=0; i<countries.length; i++) {

    console.log(countries[i]);
  }
}

console.log(init());
```

me aparece la siguiente lista:

```
USA
France
Italy
Brazil
Colombia
Belize
Venezuela
undefined
USA
France
Italy
Brazil
Colombia
Belize
Venezuela
```

y esta se vuelve a repetir, debo ponerle un condicional que no me deje hacer el loop de nuevo?

Comment: Estas mandando a imprimir el valor que retorna `init`, y pues `init` no retorna nada, por eso imprime `undefined`. manda a ejecutar init asi `init();` y no de esta forma `console.log(init());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos solo debes mandar a llamar a la funcion algo asi:

```js
function init() {
  var countries = ['USA','France','Italy','Brazil','Colombia','Belize','Venezuela'];
 total = countries.length;
  for(i=0; i<total; i++) {
    console.log(countries[i]);
  }
}
//llamando a la funcion init
init();
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Vale amigo!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Al declararla solo como funtion esta se ejecuta en la interpretacion del javascript al inicio.

declarala con un nombre y elimina el console.log que usas para llamarlo.

```js
const listarPaises=function () {
  var countries = ['USA','France','Italy','Brazil','Colombia','Belize','Venezuela'];

  for(i=0; i<countries.length; i++) {

    console.log(countries[i]);
  }
}

llamado: 
listarPaises();
```